How can I install custom plugins in Kong using declarative configuration?
I have a Kong setup based on Docker, configured in declarative mode (YAML manifest).
Reference docs: Kong | DB-less and Declarative Configuration.
Kong Docker Setup
File kong_install.bat:
@echo off

docker run -d ^
--name kong-dbless ^
--network=kong-net ^
-v "C:/path/to/config/:/kong/declarative/" ^
-e "KONG_DATABASE=off" ^
-e "KONG_DECLARATIVE_CONFIG=/kong/declarative/kong.yml" ^
-e "KONG_PROXY_ACCESS_LOG=/dev/stdout" ^
-e "KONG_ADMIN_ACCESS_LOG=/dev/stdout" ^
-e "KONG_PROXY_ERROR_LOG=/dev/stderr" ^
-e "KONG_ADMIN_ERROR_LOG=/dev/stderr" ^
-e "KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN=0.0.0.0:8001, 0.0.0.0:8444 ssl" ^
-e "KONG_ADMIN_GUI_URL=http://localhost:8002" ^
-p 8000:8000 ^
-p 8443:8443 ^
-p 127.0.0.1:8001:8001 ^
-p 127.0.0.1:8444:8444 ^
kong:3.6.1

pause

Kong Declarative Config
Here's my kong.yml manifest:
_format_version: "3.0"
_transform: true

services:
- name: example_service
  protocol: http
  host: httpbin.org
  port: 80
  routes:
  - name: example_route
    paths:
    - /mock
    strip_path: true
    
plugins:
- name: rate-limiting
  route: example_route
  config:
    second: 1
    minute: 10
    policy: local

Custom Plugin "log-test"
I have a simple custom plugin that logs some message in the Kong gateway, during the processing of the request headers.
File handler.lua:
local LOG_TEST_Handler = {}

LOG_TEST_Handler.PRIORITY = 1000
LOG_TEST_Handler.VERSION = "1.0.0"
LOG_TEST_Handler.NAME = "log-test"

function LOG_TEST_Handler:header_filter(config)
  kong.log("LOG.header_filter: start\n\n")
  
  kong.log("LOG.header_filter:\nHello world from log-test custom plugin\n\n")
  
  kong.log("LOG.header_filter: end\n\n")
end

return LOG_TEST_Handler

File schema.lua:
local typedefs = require "kong.db.schema.typedefs"

return {
  name = "log-test",
  no_consumer = true, -- This plugin does not require a Consumer to be configured.
  fields = {
  },
}

Question
Is there a way to configure (possibly in a declarative way, i.e. via YAML manifest) Kong to install custom plugins? I've searched the documentation for hours but couldn't find anything related, except for kong.conf "lua_package_path".

How do you install the plugin in your docker ?

@Ôrel I don't know how, that's the issue :') Maybe I wasn't clear enough in my question

Have you check this https://docs.konghq.com/gateway/latest/plugin-development/distribution/#via-a-dockerfile-or-docker-run-install-and-load ?
